# Angular Make items show or not on event (value change)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Basically i got this stackblitz with the demo of what i got: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r4smpy and I want it to when the value of the slider changes it checks what values in the li are in between the values of the range slider and to only show those which are. Basically if the slider range is: 100-400 it only shows values between it so in this case the 450 doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So you want to only display the numbers between *minValue* and *maxValue*.**

I created an array containing those numbers (precos) and displayed them using **ngFor** and **ngIf** to check if they actually are between min and max value.

Here's the stackblitz I edited for you:

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zovrso

Comment: Basically that's it yes